# Why variable of hashMap in Kotlin doesn't inherent the value?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

This is a `hashMap` variable:

```
val ordinaryYear = hashMapOf(Pair("January", 31), Pair("February", 28), Pair("March", 31),
    Pair("April", 31), Pair("May", 31), Pair("June", 30), Pair("Jule", 31), Pair("August", 31),
    Pair("September", 30), Pair("October", 31), Pair("November", 30), Pair("December", 31))
```

I create the new one for leap years with changed February.

```
var leapYear = ordinaryYear
    leapYear["February"] = 2999999
    println(leapYear["February"])
    println(ordinaryYear["February"])
```

If we `println()` both variables we can see the same result - `2999999` - both in case of `leapYear` and `ordinaryYear`!

How we can see, adding the new value for `February` changed the value for `February` in the previous variable. How it is possible to make a new `hashMap` variable without changing the origins?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: val leapYear = HashMap(ordinaryYear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it with

```
    val leapYear = hashMapOf<String,Int>()
    leapYear.putAll(ordinaryYear)
```

see sample here:
https://pl.kotl.in/ehj24XiX3